# How to alter mail-from postfix?

Tags: postfix

do anyone know how to alter the mail-from of a postfix mail server?

Example, I have a postfix mail server which sends mail for the domain example.org.

When a linux user, whose account is user.example.org (mapped in postfix/virtual to user@example.org), try to send an email, its mail from is user.example.org@host.example.org.

```
HELO hostname:  server.hostname.org
Source IP:      one ip here
mail-from:      user.example.org@server.hostname.org
```

Problems:

`user.example.org` instead of just `user`.

`server.hostname.org` instead of just `example.org`.

Desired mail-from: `user@example.org`.

This is causing me problems with SPF records for example (example.org differs from server.hostname.org)... any idea of what can be the problem?

Thanks in advance, Simon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can have per user HELO hostname without having a separate instance of postfix for each user.

for info on how to mangle message contents see header_checks(5) manpage http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html

Answer (score 0):

See [address masquerading](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#masquerade) in the postfix manual.